# Override an interface?

Tags: java, interface, minecraft, overriding, minecraft-forge

I am creating a mod for the game Minecraft, which has an interface to implement in-game commands. I need the mod to implement that interface, but override one of its methods with a non-compatible method (different return type). But I need to prevent a situation where other classes that implement that interface will not work or not be recognized by the game.

I think this would require overriding the interface with a new interface that is the same as the original, but with an overloaded version of that method to support the mod's needs. Is this possible (or is there another way I can accomplish this?)

Comment: Is the different return type a subtype of the original return type?

Comment: You can't override a method with one that returns a different type. Subclass the Interface and add a new method, with a different name.

Comment: Be more specific. It's likely that this interface is being called by the minecraft engine, so unless you are modifying that, the different return type won't be useful to the caller. What's the interface? What consumes it? Why do you "need" to modify it?

Comment: if the interface has a method, say, `int getIntVaue();` you don't want to try to override that using `double getIntValue();` Subclass it and add a new method `double getDoubleValue();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The interfaces supplied by Mojang/forge team are intended for use within the mojang/forge code. They expect the result types to be returned that the interfaces return. If they don't get that as defined by the contract/interface the code will crash/not compile.

It seems as if you are trying to use an interface for a particular purpose for an own project/api.
Consider writing a new interface specifically for the purpose you intend to use it for. Don't modify core interfaces.

A class can inherit multiple interfaces, so that's not an issue. You can implement AND the forge/mojang interface AND your own.

Answer (score 2):

One way to think about interfaces is as a contract.
Implementing classes must *strictly* adhere to this contract. 
This means that the method signatures (including return values and parameter) must match exactly.
The entire point of interfaces is to define the interaction without strictly knowing the implementation.

If the interaction you are looking to implement is different then it's possible that you are trying to use something in a way it wasn't intended for.

Even if it is possible to subclass an interface, it's going to quickly get messy.
It's probably in you best interest to create a new interface (with all the other methods the same). 
Since it's not going to be comparable with classes that use interface A, you are saving yourself trouble by separating it entirely.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the mod class. Then override the method. Also write another method which will overload the method in your implemented class. That way you won't have to change the interface.